# TypeError can not convert undefined or null to an object

Tags: javascript, lodash

I am trying to filter the data , using lodash function.

```
if (
      !_.isEqual(toJS(this.originalName), toJS(this.nameData)) &&
      this.marks.subject.length
    ) {

    let NameKeys = _.filter(Object.keys(this.nameData), key =>
                key.startsWith('Jo-')
              )

}
```

So, Here I am getting this exception. I here `Object.keys()` is getting set to `null`.

How do I add check for this ? Or fix this error.

Comment: `this.nameData` is either `null` or `undefined`. Can you include the code where `this.nameData` is set?

Comment: Please check the updated code

Comment: Simplest way is replace `Object.keys(this.nameData)` with `Object.keys(this.nameData || {})`

Comment: @SimonBrahan here it is undefined

Comment: @ganeshk your problem isn't in the code you've provided then; you need to check the code that populates `this.nameData`.

Answer (score 1):

first you can check whether it's actual object or not

```
function isThisRealObject(x) {
   return x && // not null, undefined, false, 0, or ''
       typeof x !== 'number' && 
       typeof x !== 'boolean' && 
       typeof x !== 'string';
}
```

Then you can call this function from where you need to check this

```
function findKeysFromObject(x) {
    return isThisRealObject(x) && Object.keys(x).length > 0;
}
```